# How to maintain integrity of a LDAP system together with a relational database?

Tags: java, postgresql, ldap, rdbms, referential-integrity

Currently i'm developing an application which authenticates the users against an external LDAP system. The applications specific data is saved in a relational database though.

My question is if there is a design pattern or something like a best practice to maintain referential integrity in my database concerning the user entries?

One of my ideas was to grab an unique identifier of the user from the LDAP system (once the first login of this user occurs) and store this together with a generated primary key in a table in my database. If I do it like this I would be able to reference the primary key in my other tables. Is this a good approach? Are there any better alternatives?

I'm using an Active Directory, a java backend and a postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is essentially the approach I've taken for applications that store user login info (or really any LDAP related info) in a separate database.

Basically when they login decode their `objectGuid` attribute value to get their UUID and use that UUID string to do the rest of their lookups in the database. This helps a lot on user account renames, as you can just lookup the UUID and if it matches then re-sync the user's data (if any else is saved in the DB).